# Echo HTML within PHP where to place quotes

Tags: php, sql, echo, quotes

I'm doing something wrong with the first line, its the quotes:

```
  <td><? echo"<a href='edit.php?id=" . "$row['adminuser_id']" . "'>Edit</a>";?></td>
```

should work as this works

```
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['adminuser_id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
```

Comment: Try `<td><?php echo"<a href='edit.php?id=" . "$row['adminuser_id']" . "'>Edit</a>";?></td>` I added the `php`. Not sure if it will work though, but try it.

Comment: <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?=$row['adminuser_id'];?>">Edit</a></td>

Comment: No luck @Fred just a blank page

Comment: @RoyalBg post your answer I will select it, it worked. Thanks

Comment: No worries, posted it as an answer with some explaination. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was requested by the author, I will post it as an answer.

In most of the cases you don't need to echo HTML tags. You better not. Echo only that part, that is dynamically, in your case - the variable.

As of PHP 5.5, the shorthand echo tag `<?=` is enabled by default as standalone tag, it has nothing to do with that short tags `<?` which are disabled, you can use without any worries the short echo to achieve this:

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?=$row['adminuser_id'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Of course, you can use it the all time way:

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['adminuser_id'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

But in both cases, you only echo the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the quotes incorrectly. Try the following:

```
<td><?php echo "<a href='edit.php?id=".$row['adminuser_id']."'>Edit</a>";?></td>
```

While the above code is syntactically correct, the following would be more cleaner (since you're already in the `<?php` context):

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['adminuser_id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

For example, if `$row['adminuser_id']` is `foo`, then both the above snippets will produce a link with the URL:

```
http://example.com/edit.php?id=foo
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why to echo the tags, when he can only echo the variable?

Comment: @RoyalBg & Fred: Yes, updated with a cleaner version. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['adminuser_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
```